# MySQL procedure while loop: Gets stuck after one iteration - Cache Clean up

Tags: mysql, caching, join, while-loop

There are some very large tables (*TargetTable*) that I am querying against, and there is a particular procedure that get stuck in its second iteration and never finishes nor crashes. The first iteration always finishes in less than a few minutes, regardless of the start of the range (*loopIndex*) or size of the of the range (*loopStepShort*).

I look forward hearing your thoughts and suggestions.

**[Update 1]** This problem goes away if I do one of the following:

- Remove the nested part of the inner-join;
- Use an in-memory temporary table for the nested part of the inner join (thanks to  @SashaPachev);
- Run each loop iteration outside of the while loop;
- Use a smaller *TargetTable*.

**[Update 2]** **Solved!** I think the problem might have been occurred, when some of databases indexes were not copied on the process of database transition. Because, when I tried to reproduce an example, it was occurring for non-indexed tables (High CPU usage and virtually infinite loop step) [MariaDB Server, JIRA](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-9342).

---

The custom configurations of the MySQL InnoDB engine (10.0.21-MariaDB Server, Linux x86_64, Fedora v.21) is as the following:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
net_write_timeout = 1800
net_read_timeout = 1800
join_buffer_size = 2G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
max_allowed_packet = 4G
key_buffer = 2G
sort_buffer_size = 512K
```

And the procedure body is as the following:

```
SET loopIndex = 0;
SET loopMax = 20000000;
SET loopStepShort = 10000;
WHILE loopIndex < loopMax do    
    UPDATE TargetTable AS t0,
        (SELECT __index, sessionStartAge
        FROM SubjectTable AS t0
        INNER JOIN (SELECT t0.id, t0.admission, 
                    if(t0.startage is null and t0.endage is null, 21, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 1, 1, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 4, 2, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 9, 3, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 14, 4, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 19, 5, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 24, 6, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 29, 7, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 34, 8, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 39, 9, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 44, 10, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 49, 11, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 54, 12, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 59, 13, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 64, 14, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 69, 15, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 74, 16, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 79, 17, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 84, 18, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 89, 19, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 120, 20, 21))))))))))))))))))))) AS sessionStartAge
            FROM SubjectTable AS t0
            INNER JOIN ids AS t1 ON t0.id = t1.id 
                AND t1.id >= loopIndex 
                AND t1.id < (loopIndex + loopStepShort)
            GROUP BY t0.id, t0.admission) AS t1 
        ON t0.id = t1.id AND t0.admission = t1.admission) AS t1
    SET t0.sessionStartAge = t1.sessionStartAge
    WHERE t0.__index = t1.__index;

    SET loopIndex = loopIndex + loopStepShort;
END WHILE;
```

Finally, below are approximate dimensions of the tables:

- **TABLE: ids:**

  - TABLE ROWS: *~1,500,000 records,*
  - DATA LENGTH: *~250 MB,*
  - INDEX LENGTH: *~140 MB,*
  - TABLE SIZE: *~400 MB*
- **TABLE: TargetTable:**

  - TABLE ROWS: *~6,500,000 records,*
  - DATA LENGTH: *~4 GB,*
  - INDEX LENGTH: *~350 MB,*
  - TABLE SIZE: *~4.35 MB*
- **TABLE: SubjectTable:**

  - TABLE ROWS: *~6,500,000 records,*
  - DATA LENGTH: *~550 MB,*
  - INDEX LENGTH: *N/A,*
  - TABLE SIZE: *~550 MB*

Many thanks in advance.

---

I guess I have to raise a bug report to Oracle/MariaDB, and update the post.

Comment: Updating in loop like that does not seem to be too efficient. Can you pls explain what you would like to achive with the above code, just in case we can suggest another solution.

Comment: Again, when do you commit the changes?

Comment: The purpose of this procedure, which is shorten here for clarity reason, is to find minimum age (*sessionStartAge*) of a client (*id*) for each session. Each client has a number of visit, which can be categorized to sessions, and each session can include one or more visits that have similar admission date (*admission*). Also, note that the procedure works fine outside of the loop, it is something about while loop that messes it up. Thanks

Comment: I have added the discretisation (*if statements*) to the query in here, which is part of the  originally my query. I believe it is the major contributing factor after a few runs.

Comment: Also, about the commit: *"By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent. The change cannot be rolled back."* [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html)

Comment: I was wrong about the if statements, their contributions to the slow down is very small. My update on the causes: This problem goes away if I do one of the following: [**1**] Remove the nested inner-join;  [**2**] Run each loop iteration outside of the while loop;   [**3**]  Use a smaller (*TargetTable*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (disclaimer - untested, may contain syntax errors or bugs):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (key(id)) ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT t0.id, t0.admission, 
                    if(t0.startage is null and t0.endage is null, 21, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 1, 1, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 4, 2, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 9, 3, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 14, 4, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 19, 5, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 24, 6, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 29, 7, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 34, 8, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 39, 9, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 44, 10, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 49, 11, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 54, 12, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 59, 13, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 64, 14, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 69, 15, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 74, 16, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 79, 17, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 84, 18, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 89, 19, 
                    if(least(t0.startage, t0.endage) <= 120, 20, 21)))))))))))))))))))) as sessionStartAge,
FROM SubjectTable AS t0
            INNER JOIN ids AS t1 ON t0.id = t1.id 
                AND t1.id >= loopIndex 
                AND t1.id < (loopIndex + loopStepShort)
            GROUP BY t0.id, t0.admission;
UPDATE TargetTable AS t0,
        (SELECT __index, sessionStartAge
        FROM SubjectTable AS t0
        INNER JOIN t1 ON t0.id = t1.id AND t0.admission = t1.admission) AS t2
    SET t0.sessionStartAge = t1.sessionStartAge
    WHERE t0.__index = t2.__index;
```

The idea is to replace the inner sub-query with a temporary table with a key, so that the outside join could use that key.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @Sasha-Pachev. The solution you provided works. I think I have to send it to Oracle/MariaDB as a bug report .

Comment: One long issue with a sub-select in MySQL is that if a temporary table is created to store the output of the sub-query, no effort is made to predict what keys might be good for it. It may have been addressed in the recent versions of MySQL/MariaDB, but as of 5.5 I believe you are still out of luck. My approach is to assume the sub-query optimizer is limited and create temporary tables manually with the right keys whenever I am in doubt as to the optimizer's ability to properly deal with the sub-query.